# how to make reactstrap carousel as shorter in size with left menu options?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm using reactstrap carousel in an application, but found problem when trying to make it shorter in size and a left ul menu with react.

```
import React from 'react';

import Shelf from '../Shelf';
import Filter from '../Shelf/Filter';
import GithubCorner from '../github/Corner';
import FloatCart from '../FloatCart';
import ControlledCarousel from './ControlledCarousel';

const App = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <GithubCorner />
        <main>          
             <ControlledCarousel />            
             <Filter />  
            <Shelf />           
    </main>
    <FloatCart />
  </React.Fragment>
);

export default App;

--===================================================

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Carousel,
    CarouselItem,
    CarouselControl,
    CarouselIndicators,
    CarouselCaption
} from 'reactstrap';

 import './style.scss';

const items = [
    {
        src: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_15ba800aa1d%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23555%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_15ba800aa1d%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22285.921875%22%20y%3D%22218.3%22%3EFirst%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E',
        altText: 'Slide 1',
        caption: 'Slide 1'
    },
    {
        src: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_15ba800aa20%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23444%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_15ba800aa20%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23666%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22247.3203125%22%20y%3D%22218.3%22%3ESecond%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E',
        altText: 'Slide 2',
        caption: 'Slide 2'
    },
    {
        src: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_15ba800aa21%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23333%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_15ba800aa21%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23555%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22277%22%20y%3D%22218.3%22%3EThird%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E',
        altText: 'Slide 3',
        caption: 'Slide 3'
    }
];

class ControlledCarousel extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { activeIndex: 0 };
        this.next = this.next.bind(this);
        this.previous = this.previous.bind(this);
        this.goToIndex = this.goToIndex.bind(this);
        this.onExiting = this.onExiting.bind(this);
        this.onExited = this.onExited.bind(this);
    }

    onExiting() {
        this.animating = true;
    }

    onExited() {
        this.animating = false;
    }

    next() {
        if (this.animating) return;
        const nextIndex = this.state.activeIndex === items.length - 1 ? 0 : this.state.activeIndex + 1;
        this.setState({ activeIndex: nextIndex });
    }

    previous() {
        if (this.animating) return;
        const nextIndex = this.state.activeIndex === 0 ? items.length - 1 : this.state.activeIndex - 1;
        this.setState({ activeIndex: nextIndex });
    }

    goToIndex(newIndex) {
        if (this.animating) return;
        this.setState({ activeIndex: newIndex });
    }

    render() {
        const { activeIndex } = this.state;

        const slides = items.map((item) => {
            return (
                <CarouselItem className="slider-cart"
                    onExiting={this.onExiting}
                    onExited={this.onExited}
                    key={item.src}
                >
                    <img src={item.src} alt={item.altText} />
                    <CarouselCaption captionText={item.caption} captionHeader={item.caption} />
                </CarouselItem>
            );
        });

        return (
            <Carousel className="slider-cart"
                activeIndex={activeIndex}
                next={this.next}
                previous={this.previous} >
                <CarouselIndicators items={items} activeIndex={activeIndex} onClickHandler={this.goToIndex} />
                {slides}
                <CarouselControl direction="prev" directionText="Previous" onClickHandler={this.previous} />
                <CarouselControl direction="next" directionText="Next" onClickHandler={this.next} />
            </Carousel>
        );
    }
}


export default ControlledCarousel;

--===========================================

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider-cart {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;  
    left:10px;
    width: 450px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #1b1a20;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: right 0.2s;
}

.carousel {
    width: 900px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
    .carousel {
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

The code reports a problem and I have no idea with it since I'm a newbie with react-redux. What should I do in my code?

I've grabbed the example code for a carousel from here: https://reactstrap.github.io/components/carousel/

Application built with 16.9.0", "react-dom": "^16.9.0", "react-redux": "^7.1.0", "reactstrap": "^8.0.1","redux": "^4.0.4" and "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0".

The container uses the react custom component, which is disturbing the the layout.

Output:

[image]

I tried to follow guides and looked up example implementations but could not solve the issue.

reactjs reactstrap